# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'foreman' (>= 0)

Tags: terminal, vagrant

I am trying to run on my vagrant machine

```
sudo gem install foreman --source http://rubygems.org
```

But i am getting the following error.

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'foreman' (>= 0), here is why:           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (ht tps://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: Does your vagrant box have internet access?  (curl -L http://www.google.com)

Comment: Or maybe it is a DNS issue?